# javascript eventlistener function argument

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, event-listener

I am trying to add eventlistener to input elements on an html with an inputListener function with a parameter as shown below. But this way does not work. I do not understand why I cannot pass the parameter to eventlistener function.

```
for (let index = 0; index<inputElements.length; index ++) {
  inputElements[index].addEventListener("input",inputListener(index));
}

function inputListener(index){
  if (inputElements[index].value.length>=5) {
      inputElements[index].style.border="none";
  }
  else{
       inputElements[index].style.border="solid 3px red";
 }
}`
```

Comment: Read this [addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) page for example.

Comment: *"I do not understand why I cannot pass the parameter to eventlistener function."* `addEventListener` expects to be passed a function. You are passing the **return value** of `inputListener`, which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the element reference from within the event listener using `this` and not by passing `index` in the listener function. Since you are validating the length of the text inside the `input` element you could use `keyup` event listener for that and validate for the length of the text.

```js
var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (let index = 0; index<inputElements.length; index ++) {
  inputElements[index].addEventListener("keyup",inputListener);
}

function inputListener(){
  if (this.value.length>=5) {
      this.style.border="none";
  }
  else{
       this.style.border="solid 3px red";
 }
}
```

```html
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But I do not want to use keyup since I want to catch the input value continiously even while any key pressed an held. Keyup only validates when key is up.

Comment: What if I want to pass a parameter to inputlistener function other than the index parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try by calling it from the callback function

```
function inputListener(index) {
  if (inputElements[index].value.length >= 5) {
    inputElements[index].style.border = "none";
  } else {
    inputElements[index].style.border = "solid 3px red";
  }
}

for (let index = 0; index < inputElements.length; index++) {
  inputElements[index].addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    inputListener(index)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's enough to use the keyword "this" from within the function to refer the object (inputElements[index]), no need to pass the index.